# Correlation between the linear combinations of bivariate normal distributed variables

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, bivariate

How can I find the correlation (rho) between $U$ and $V$,  Where $U = X_1+X_2$ and $V= X_1-2X_2$ 
$X_1$ and $X_2$ are normally distributed with $\mu= 1$ and $\sigma= 2$.

Comment: are $X_1$ and $X_2$ independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the result that a linear combination of normally distributed random variables is also normal, in this case X is bivariate normal.

\begin{equation}
    \textbf{X}_{p=2} = 
\begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\ X_2 \end{bmatrix} \in N_{p=2}( \bf{ \mu_x }, \bf{ \Sigma_x } ) = N\left( \begin{bmatrix}
\mu_1 =1 \\ \mu_2 =1
\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix}
2 & \sigma_{12} \\
\sigma_{21} & 2 
\end{bmatrix}  \right) 
\end{equation}
Then 
\begin{equation}
    \bf{A}\bf{X} = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & -2
    \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\ X_2 \end{bmatrix} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    X_1 + X_2 \\
    X_1 -2X_2
    \end{bmatrix} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    U \\ V
    \end{bmatrix} \in N_{p=2} \left(\bf{A}\bf{\mu_x}, \bf{A}\bf{\Sigma_x}\bf{A}'    \right) 
\end{equation}
Finally calculate $\rho = \sigma_{12}/(\sqrt{\sigma_{11}}\sqrt{\sigma_{22}})$ from the entries of $\bf{A}\bf{\Sigma}\bf{A}'$, which is the correlation between U and V. Note that $\sigma_{11},\sigma_{22}$ denotes the variances (just notation).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent so
$$cov(U,V)=cov(X_1+X_2,X_1-2X_2)$$
$$=cov(X_1,X_1)+cov(X_2,-2X_2)$$
$$=cov(X_1,X_1)-2cov(X_2,X_2)$$